# Deployed React + Node.js application to Heroku and receiving Cannot GET / Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have been working with another developer and we have been able to deploy the React + Node.js application using Express to Heroku, however we are still receiving an error as shown below in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I am apparently getting a 404 from the server and I feel that we are close to resolving the problem; we just do not know if it is a simple syntax fix or structure in general.

Here is my root package.json file:

```html
{
  "name": "dev-personal-portfolio-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified \" && exit 1",
    "post-build": "cd client && npm i && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Here is the server.js file:

```html
require ('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const buildPath = ('build/index.html');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const sendGrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.use(cors());

// server.use((req, res, next) => {
//   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
//   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
//   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
//   next();
// });

// server.get('/api', (req, res, next) => {
//   res.send('API Status: Running')
// });


server.use(express.static('client/build'));
// server.use('/static', express.static('public'))
// server.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './public')));

// server.get('*', (req, res) => {
//     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
// });
console.log(express.static('client/build'));
console.log(`${__dirname}/public/index.html`);
server.use(express.json());

const REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY =`${process.env.REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY}`
server.post('/api/email', (req, res, next) => {
  sendGrid.setApiKey(REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  console.log(req.body);
  const msg = {
      to: 'kevgill95@gmail.com',
      from: req.body.email,
      subject: req.body.subject,
      text: req.body.message
  }

  sendGrid.send(msg)
      .then(result => {
          res.status(200).json({
            success: true
          });

      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log('error: ', err);
          res.status(401).json({
            success: false
          })
      })
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}!`);
});
```

NOTE: for the console.logs, here is what is returning from them:

console.log(express.static('client/build'));
[Function: serveStatic]

console.log(`${__dirname}/public/index.html`);
/Users/kevingillooly/dev-personal-portfolio-2/public/index.html

We have tried commenting out lines of code as well to try to resolve the problem, but we have not encountered anything that works.

If anyone would know what the problem would be, that would be awesome. The build succeeds just fine however the problem is very vague and we have tried a lot of different methods.

Comment: couple of ideas.   have you moved the build from the client folder to the main folder?  in development, are you running react on a seperare port than express, amd if.so do you have a proxy setup?  does your package.json file reflect all of the start scripts needed to run the app?

Comment: @Hyetigran is the other developer on this project

Comment: @Jondreisbach at the moment, heroku is building the server and the postbuild script cd's into the client folder and runs npm i && npm build. In development, they run on separate ports but the idea was to have them run on the same port in production. Not sure about proxy setups.

Comment: @Jon dreisbach I can upload the package.json from the root folder if you would like me to

Comment: @kevgill95, assuming everything in development is working fine, move the minified build folder to the root directory and make sure you add, commit and push from the root directory.